# How to change layout of Bootstrap thumbnail in Drupal 7 views

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am working on Drupal 7 with bootstrap sub-theme and I want to achieve this [image: drupal 7 view] dynamic view of Top News, where the first item has image on the right while title and body on the left with the other two items imitate a traditional bootstrap thumbnail (image on top/bottom and content vice versa).

I have tried many tricks but I cannot seems to achieve this using Views Bootstrap Drupal 7 module. Using Views Bootstrap, I only achieved the second and third items but I cannot make the first item look like in the picture.

Can somebody give me an hint or any other way to achieve this whether or not using Views modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make it in single view, You have to create 2 block of same view, Top block and bottom, in top block you can show your first item using paging and make the style as you want for image cache, and in bottom block you can skip first item using paging and make the style as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you *could* use only one view.

Just create 2 blocks in the same view, where the first block is the first item, and the second block are the 2nd and 3rd items.

Another option, you could create just one display, and then an "attachment" display that is attached the main display.

Also, I find view bootstrap not that helpful. If you know where to inject classes in your fields/components in views, you should just use normal "unformatted" format and just add your standard bootstrap classes.